# Pointer to related research (papers)

Tags: quantum-computing

Recently, I was reading a paper (arXiv:1804.03719 [cs.ET]), which had the following quote (the most relevant part has been bolded),

> Quantum algorithms are often grouped into number-theory-based, oracle- based, and quantum simulation algorithms,
>   such as for instance on the excellent Quantum Zoo site [57], which is largely based on the main quantum algorithmic
>   paradigm that these algorithms use. These paradigms are the Quantum Fourier Transform (QFT), the Grover Operator
>   (GO), the Harrow/Hassidim/Lloyd (HHL) method for linear systems, variational quantum eigenvalue solver (VQE),
>   and direct Hamiltonian simulation (SIM). The fact that most known quantum algorithms are based on these few
>   paradigms in combination is remarkable and perhaps surprising. **The discovery of additional quantum algorithm
>   paradigms, which should be the subject of intense research, could make quantum algorithms applicable across a much
>   wider range of applications**.

I am very interested in exploring the topic of quantum algorithm paradigms. However, my usual approach of following the reference trail failed to unearth any relevant papers.

If anyone has any suggestions regarding where to look, or know any relevant papers, I would appreciate your input.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be better to post this question to https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com, there are a lot of quantum students and researchers there who should be able to point you to relevant resources.

Comment: Did not know that existed, thanks!